# git cloning cygwin is failing each time with while reading sideband packet fatal. fatal: index-pack

Tags: git

I have typed:

```
export PATH=/bin:$PATH
```

Then I try to clone, and get:

```
$ git clone ssh://********.git
Cloning into 'selenium_automation'...
remote: Counting objects: 83117, done
remote: Finding sources: 100% (83117/83117)
remote: Getting sizes: 100% (28060/28060)
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (2604425/2604425)
client_loop: se
nd disconnect: Connection reset by peer.00 KiB/s
fetch-pack: unexpected disconnect while reading sideband packet
fatal: early EOF
fatal: index-pack failed
```

Each time at the "Receiving object" stage its getting stuck at 69% and then failing with above error

```
client_loop: send disconnect: Connection reset by peer.00 KiB/s
fetch-pack: unexpected disconnect while reading sideband packet
fatal: early EOF
fatal: index-pack failed"
```

How can I avoid this error?

Answer (score 0):

Since this error message has changed recently (Git 2.30, Q1 2021), try and:

- install [Git for Windows](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases) (which comes with its own bash shell)
- check if the issue persists when cloning with that git instead of the Cygwin one.

If it does, the remote repository might be corrupted.
Check first if you can clone another repository from the same remote server, to rule out any network issue.